# Safari consuming a lot of juice on rMB 2016 with Mojave

Tags: safari, battery

I hope you're all doing good and staying safe.

To make things short. I've upgraded to Mojave a month ago, since I couldn't push ElCap for longer.
Until last month, my batt life was impeccable (I never let battery go below 60%, never overinflated it, etc etc).
I could get more than an hour without the full batt icon even showing a bit of usage.
So I can know for sure the batt is not the problem. Neither is the computer. I've used my computer on several 10+ hours and the battery life has always been exceptional.

I moved on to Mojave, and now my batt starts draining after less than 30 mins usage.

I knew this might happen, that's why I sticked to ElCap.. but due to security reasons and app compatibility, I had to do the jump. Now I kinda regret it.

Thing is, only thing showing a hug Avg NRG impact is Safari.
I know some might say *"it's AVERAGE, not current"*, yeah, but I have many other apps opened along with safari, and they don't even get to a 10% of what Safari consumes in average.

Any ideas on how to get Safari behaving properly? Or any browser that avg impact doesn't rise 300 and above?

I am also considering downgrading to ElCap, but would like to keep Mojave though.

Thanks in advance for any kind of input! :-)

Comment: I don't think it's specific to Safari but rather to websites you are viewing, as more and more of them are demanding more memory/CPU as computers get more advanced. You could check what extensions installed in Safari preferences. Additionally, it would be good to see under Website settings to see if you've enabled/disabled auto-play, content blockers, plugins (like Adobe Flash), etc., as these will also impact performance/slow down website loading. You can also try another web browser and see how that goes? Note, I use Safari on my 2013 MBP on Mojave and it works fine for me.

Comment: @AVelj: Indeed that seemed to be _sort of_ the case. I killed all pinned tabs and it was working a bit better. However, Safari keeps brutalizing power usage over time, in a way I never seen on El Cap. Also I visit the same pages, I'm not really doing anything new. Oh well, I guess it's the perks of upgrading software. I wonder if I switch to a new MBPro it will keep the extremely long battery life I had with my rMB 12. 